# Determine third point of triangle when two points are known

Tags: geometry

and spent half day but could not find answer. I don not remember any ways to solve it. I has been 10 years since I graduated.
But as I remember answer should be easy.

[image]

Comment: As a hint, the slope of the line from $A$ to $B$ is very closely related to the slope from $B$ to the ending point.  As for passing through lattice points, consider reducing a particular useful fraction to simplest form.  Rather than $\frac{-2}{4}$ for instance using $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints.

1. Calculate the vector as you go from $A$ to $B$.

   > Start with the components of $B$ and subtract the corresponding components of $A$. So the $x$ component of the vector in the picture would be $3 - (-1) = 4$. Similarly for the $y$ component.
2. Calculate the vector going in the new direction.

   > Switch the coordinates, and change the sign of the $y$ coordinate after you switch. If the vector you found in Step 1 were $(4,-5)$, the new vector would be $(-5,-4)$.
3. Find the greatest common factor of the $x$ and $y$ components of this new vector, and divide it out.

   > Javascript may have a function that does this for you, [or you can check here](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-8.php).
4. Add this vector to the location of $B$.

   > Add the components of $B$ and the vector you found in Step 3.

Comment: yeh, but problem is that, I do not remember all those staff and not sure how can I calculate vectors in vanilla javascript

Comment: Added some more hints in between. Hover over with your mouse if you get stuck.